# inequality with exponents

Tags: pr.probability, graph-theory, inequalities

We are given a graph $G$, each vertex $v$ has an assigned value $\gamma_v\in [0,1]$, and it happens that for every $v$ we have $\gamma_v+\sum_{u\in \delta(v)} \gamma_u = 1$. Assume that $\sum_v \gamma_v = k$ some integer value. For every vertex $v$ there is also a number $a_v\in [0,1]$. That's the structural setup.

Now, for every $\lambda > 0$ we want to prove the following inequality:
$$\frac{1}{k}\sum_v \gamma_v\cdot e^{-(e^\lambda-1)(a_v\gamma_v+\sum_{u\in \delta(v)}a_u\gamma_u)+\lambda a_v} \leq 1.$$
It has a probabilistic interpretation, if you find it helpful: we pick randomly a vertex proportionally to $\gamma_v$ we pick a value $a_v$ then, and remove $a_u\gamma_u$ from every neighbor of $v$, we then look at the expected value of exponentiated change.

The inequality is true, when the graph is a clique and $k=\sum_v \gamma_v=1$. Then we can take advantage of the fact that for every $v$ we have $a_v\gamma_v+\sum_{u\in \delta(v)}a_u\gamma_u = \sum_v a_v\gamma_v$ always the same. In this case the proof goes as follows:
\begin{align}
\sum_{\gamma_{v}}\gamma_{v}e^{\lambda a_{v}} 
&\leq \sum_{\gamma_{v}}\gamma_{v}(a_v(e^{\lambda }-1)+1)\\
&= \sum_{\gamma_{v}}\gamma_{v}a_v(e^{\lambda }-1)+1 \\
&\leq e^{\sum_{\gamma_{v}}\gamma_{v}a_v(e^{\lambda }-1)},
\end{align}
where we used first $e^{a\lambda}-1 \leq a(e^\lambda -1)$, and then $1+x\leq e^x$ plus $\sum_v \gamma_v=1$.
I believe that in the general case it should still be true, but the approach from the simple case doesn't carry over that easily.
Any help in proving the inequality will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is $\delta(v)$? Is it the set of vertices adjacent to $v$?

Comment: Yes, the neighbors of $v$.

Comment: LHS is convex in any of variables $a_v$, hence it suffices to take $a_v\in \{0,1\}$

Comment: Good point, can it be combined with the argument below?

Comment: Maybe, it makes sense to estimate $\gamma e^{\lambda a}\leq \gamma-1+e^{\gamma a (e^{\lambda}-1)}$ in each summand. At least it becomes more pretty, though maybe false.

Comment: Alas, it becomes false. But maybe this could be modified.

Comment: Thank you Fedor for your help. From the case of $k=1$ it seems like we can drop the assumption of $\sum \gamma_v = 1$, and we can substitute it with $\sum \gamma_v \leq 1$. Also in place of integer $k$ we can just take the sum $\sum \gamma_v$. With this maybe the following idea from probabilistic interpretation will be helpful plus your remark that only 0-1 $a$-s are important: if we pick $\gamma_v$ with probability $\gamma_v/\sum \gamma_v$, then $a_v$ is the gain we collect, and $\sum_{u\in \delta(f)} a_u\gamma_u$ is the decrease in the system.

Comment: Now, if $a_v = 0$, then the exponent with decrease in the system plus the gain is clearly less than 1. Therefore, one can maybe argue that the expected value of the $E \exp( -(e^\lambda-1)decrease + \lambda \cdot gain)$ will be bigger if we would condition on choosing only $v$-s for which $a_v=1$. This expectation with conditioning may be easier to handle.

Comment: Ok, that will not work. When we take a lot lot of isolated vertices with $a_v=1$ with small $\gamma_v$, then the LHS essentially becomes $e^\lambda$

Answer (score 1):

I have some nice lines, which I think can be pushed to a full proof.

We shall show that 
$$\sum_v \gamma_v\cdot e^{-(e^\lambda-1)(a_v\gamma_v+\sum_{u\in \delta(v)}a_u\gamma_u)+\lambda a_v} =: f((a_v)_{v\in V})$$
is maximized when all $a$'s are $0$, in which case it's equal to $1$.
Denote
$$
\Delta_v := e^{-(e^\lambda-1)(a_v\gamma_v+\sum_{u\in \delta(v)}a_u\gamma_u)+\lambda a_v}
$$
The partial derivative over $a_v$ is equal to
\begin{align}
\frac{d f}{d a_v} =&\ \gamma_v \cdot \left(-\gamma_v(e^\lambda -1) + \lambda \right) \cdot e^{-(e^\lambda-1)(a_v\gamma_v+\sum_{u\in \delta(v)}a_u\gamma_u)+\lambda a_v} \\&\ + \sum_{u\in \delta(v)} \gamma_u \cdot (-\gamma_v(e^\lambda -1))\cdot e^{-(e^\lambda-1)(a_u\gamma_u+\sum_{w\in \delta(u)}a_w\gamma_w)+\lambda a_u}\\
=&\ \gamma_v \cdot \left(-\gamma_v(e^\lambda -1) + \lambda \right) \cdot \Delta_v  + \sum_{u\in \delta(v)} \gamma_u \cdot (-\gamma_v(e^\lambda -1))\cdot \Delta_u
\end{align}
Now we want to show that for some $v$, the partial derivative is negative, i.e., for some $v$ we have
$$
\left(\gamma_v(e^\lambda -1) - \lambda \right) \cdot \Delta_v  + \sum_{u\in \delta(v)} \gamma_u \cdot (e^\lambda -1)\cdot \Delta_u \geq 0\\
\leftrightarrow \\
\gamma_v  \cdot \Delta_v  + \sum_{u\in \delta(v)} \gamma_u \cdot \Delta_u \geq \frac{\lambda}{e^\lambda -1} \Delta_v \qquad (*)
$$
Assume that none of $a_v$ is equal to $0$. Multiply $(*)$ by $\gamma_v$, and sum them up together, then the LHS sums up to
\begin{align}
&\ \sum_v \gamma_v\cdot \left(\gamma_v  \cdot \Delta_v  + \sum_{u\in \delta(v)} \gamma_u \cdot \Delta_u \right)\\
=&\ \sum_v \gamma_v\cdot \Delta_v (\gamma_v+\sum_{u\in \delta(v)}\gamma_u)\\
=&\ \sum_v \gamma_v\cdot \Delta_v.
\end{align}
Now the RHS of $(*)$ sums up to $\frac{\lambda}{e^\lambda -1}\sum_v \gamma_v\cdot \Delta_v < \sum_v \gamma_v\cdot \Delta_v$, and so there has to exist $v$ for which $(*)$ is satisfied.

Once we would account for the fact that some $a_v$-s can be $0$, and prove that there exists such a $v$ for which $a_v>0$, then we could argue that the maximum is obtained when all $a_v$-s are $0$.